# Is there a setMethods() Equivalent in Mockery for Mocking Chained Methods

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, mockery

I am mocking a chain of methods.  I can get it to work fine with PHPUnit's MockBuilder; however, I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to mock them in Mockery.

My current code looks like:

```
    $this->RepositoryMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Repository')
        ->setMethods(array('method1', 'method2', 'method3'))
        ->getMock();


    $this->RepositoryMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('method1')
        ->will($this->returnSelf());
    $this->RepositoryMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('method2')
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));
    $this->RepositoryMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('method3')
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));
```

setMethods won't work when using Mockery::mock, but I would like it to look something like the following code replacing setMethods with Mockery's version:

```
    $this->RepositoryMock = Mockery::mock('Repository')
         ->setMethods('method1', 'method2', 'method3');

    $this->RepositoryMock
         ->shouldReceive('method1')
         ->andReturn($this->returnSelf())
         ->shouldReceive('method2')
         ->andReturn(true)
         ->shouldReceive('method3')
         ->andReturn(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and setMethods() was not necessary and they can be chained together fine without.

```
$this->RepositoryMock = Mockery::mock('Repository');

$this->RepositoryMock
     ->shouldReceive('method1')
     ->andReturn($this->returnSelf())
     ->shouldReceive('method2')
     ->andReturn(true)
     ->shouldReceive('method3')
     ->andReturn(true)
```